# How to enable word wrap in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I found a lot of examples and methods to word wrap in Visual Studio Code but not for VS for Mac. Currently, I'm using the Enterprise edition with the latest updates.

Comment: Word wrap is not supported in Visual Studio for Mac. If you want this feature you can vote for it on the [Visual Studio for Mac user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/17166137-text-wrapping).

Comment: so bad really, such a basic stuff

Comment: Please see the recent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Matt Ward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268874/matt-ward) for let me know that this isn't implemented yet, but I managed to play around with the preferences. It's not perfect as VS for Windows, but it's close enough.

(Sorry that the VS for Mac is in spanish)

1) I made a few modifications in text files: 120 columns and remove the whitespaces at the end of the line.

[image: Settings for plain text]

2) Since I'm using a Macbook pro mid 2012 my screen resolution it's limited to 1280x80, so in XML files I set only 3 attributes per line, adjust the attributes and align the attributes.

[image: Settings for XML and XAML files]

3) I made modifications in C# but was only to set the system's using at the end of the block.

4) Finally, I made a keyboard shortcut for "Format the document"
[image: Format the document]

Before format
[image]

After format
[image]

Answer (score 9):

As of VS Mac 8.1, Word Wrap is available via **Visual Studio -> Preferences -> Text Editor -> General.** You should see a checkbox option for Word wrap.

[image]

8.1 Release Notes:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2019-mac-relnotes-v8.1